# ¿Como agregar un imagen superior al documento generado por PDF con iTextSharp en C#?

Tags: c#, itextsharp

Tengo el siguiente código usando iTextSharp:

```
Byte[] bytes;

using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
{
      using (var doc = new Document())
      {
           using (var writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(doc, ms))
           {
               doc.Open();

               var example_html = @"<p align=""justify"">Junto con saludar, quiero mostrar un ejemplo</p>";
               var example_css = @".headline{font-size:200%}";

               using (var htmlWorker = new iTextSharp.text.html.simpleparser.HTMLWorker(doc))
               {
                     using (var sr = new StringReader(example_html))
                     {
                          htmlWorker.Parse(sr);
                     }
               }
               using (var srHtml = new StringReader(example_html))
               {
                     //Parse the HTML
                     iTextSharp.tool.xml.XMLWorkerHelper.GetInstance().ParseXHtml(writer, doc, srHtml);
               }
               using (var msCss = new MemoryStream(System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(example_css)))
               {
                     using (var msHtml = new MemoryStream(System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(example_html)))
                     {
                          iTextSharp.tool.xml.XMLWorkerHelper.GetInstance().ParseXHtml(writer, doc, msHtml, msCss);
                     }
                }
                doc.Close();
         }
     }
     bytes = ms.ToArray();
 }

 var testFile = Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop), "documento.pdf");
 System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes(testFile, bytes);
```

Lo que deseo es agregar una imagen en el lado superior izquierdo o derecho que me sirva de logo en el documento pdf. ¿Como se puede hacer?
Algún ejemplo o consejo, se lo agradecería mucho.

Saludos

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Utilizo el siguiente código para fijar una imagen úsalo si te sirve

```
iTextSharp.text.Image logo = iTextSharp.text.Image.GetInstance(@"C:\XXXX\logo1.png");
logo.SetAbsolutePosition(35, 717); //esta es la ubicación en la hoja en mi caso es carta
logo.ScalePercent(20); // el tamaño de la imagen
document.Add(logo);  //lo agregas al documento
```

Previamente debiste de haber definido el tamaño de hoja 
Saludos